# The constructor is not reading the values from an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The constructor for my `Player` class is compiling, but it's not actually transferring the values of any of the fields from the `Animal` object. The `Animal` object is available, because I can use `Debug.Log()` to check for each of its values via an added `Update()` function. Are objects not capable of being accessed in a constructor?

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animal myAnimal;

    int hpMax;
    int power;
    int defense;

    Player(){
        hpMax = myAnimal.hpMax;
        power = myAnimal.power;
        defense = myAnimal.defense;
        }
}
```

And here is the imported `Animal` (a `Sheep`, actually, inherited from `Animal`):

```
public class Sheep : Animal {

    public Sheep(){
        hpMax = 100;
        power = 10;
        defense = 10;
}
```

The superclass:

```
public abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour {

    public int hpMax;
    public int power;
    public int defense;
}
```

Comment: when the player constructor is called the myanimal field will be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are setting your `myAnimal` field in the inspector or somewhere else, you can not access it in the constructor of your `Player` class, as it is not set yet. Try to do that in the `Awake` method:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animal myAnimal;

    int hpMax;
    int power;
    int defense;

    void Awake() {

        hpMax = myAnimal.hpMax;
        power = myAnimal.power;
        defense = myAnimal.defense;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create object of that animal.

If You inherit from MonoBehavior You can't create it by new keyword so - In player Constructor You need to call:

```
myAnimal = gameObject.AddComponent<Sheep>(); // You must have this gameObject somewhere
```

Or second solution - don't inherit from MonoBehaviour in Your animal class and then just creat new object of that animal:

```
private animal myAnimal = new Sheep();
```

Comment: I get the following error from making that change:

You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent().  Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all

Comment: Does animal inherit from MonoBehaviour ?

Comment: Yes.  I've included the code from that class above.

Answer (score 0):

The `Animal` object in the `Player` class won't be initialised because it's not `static` and therefore it can't exist yet.  It would be wrong to make this `static` anyway.

Consider passing the `Animal` object into the constructor - `Player(Animal animal)` or even have a static method on the Player class `Player.CreateFromAnimal(Animal animal)` which returns a new `Player`.  Furthermore, remove the public access modifier from `Animal` as this is breaking encapsulation.

Have a read of encapsulation and Object Oriented Programming in general.  It will help when design classes.

Comment: And when I say remove the public access modifier, I meant make it `public get` and `private set`.